# How to skip parts of HTML based on screenwidth / device using ejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ecmascript-6, ejs

Was wondering if it's possible to skip HTML `<TAGs>` in a page based on the screen-size of the browser. Looking to skip intensive nested `for-loops` for mobile browsers.

Thanks,

Comment: Share some code what you are trying to do, and what is going on.

Comment: Look into media queries